# Using pandas apply() function on a dataframe to create a new dataframe

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a problem annoying me for some time now. I have written a function that should, based on the row values of a dataframe, create a new dataframe filled with values based on a condition in the function. My function looks like this:

```
def intI():

    df_ = pd.DataFrame()
    df_ = df_.fillna(0)

    for index, row in Anno.iterrows():
        genes=row['AR_Genes'].split(',')
        df=pd.DataFrame()
        if 'intI1' in genes:
            df['Year']=row['Year']
            df['Integrase']= 1
            df_=df_.append(df)
        elif 'intI2' in genes:
            df['Year']=row['Year']
            df['Integrase']= 1
            df_=df_.append(df)
        else:
            df['Year']=row['Year']
            df['Integrase']= 0
            df_=df_.append(df)

    return df_
```

when I call it like this `Newdf=Anno['AR_Genes'].apply(intI())`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I really do not understand why it does not work. I have done similar things before, but there seems to be a difference that I do not get. Can anybody explain what is wrong here?

*******************EDIT*****************************

`Anno` in the function is the dataframe that the function shal be run on. It contains a string, for example `a,b,c,ad,c`

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.apply` takes a *function* which applies to all rows/columns of the DataFrame. That error occurs because your function returns a DataFrame which you then pass to `apply`.

Why do you do use `.fillna(0)` on a newly created, empty, DataFrame?

Would not this work? `Newdf = intI()`

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem. I tried you solution, but it only returns an empty dataframe with the columns 'year' and 'integrase'...